# A question about linear transformation (One-One /Onto)

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Suppose $T:\mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ is the transformation given below . Determine whether $T$ is one-to-one and/or onto. if it is not one-to-one . Show this by providing tow vectors that have the same image under $T$. I T is not onto. Show this by providing a vector in $\mathbb{R}^4$ that is not in the range of $$

$$T\begin{bmatrix}
x_0\\ 
x_1\\ 
x_2\\ 
x_3
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
2x_0-10x_1-4x_2-2x_3\\ 
x_0-5x_1+x_2+5x_3\\ 
-x_0+5x_1+3x_2+4x_3\\ 
-2x_0+10x_1+3x_2+x_3
\end{bmatrix}$$

My attempt : the matrix form standard basis is

$$\begin{bmatrix}
2 &-10  &-10  &-2 \\ 
1 &-5  &1  &5 \\ 
 -1&5  &3  &4 \\ 
 -2&10  &3  &1 
\end{bmatrix}\sim\begin{bmatrix}
1 &-5  &1  &5 \\0 
 &0  &1  &2 \\0 
 &0  &0  &1 \\0 
 &0  &0  &0 
\end{bmatrix}$$

So this transformation is neither one-to-one or onto

but i cant find examples .Is there any way to find simple way to give counter examples to show for not one-to-one or not onto

Comment: This is a pretty efficient way. Not to mention this matrix was built to be row reduced: look at the first and last row and the middle 2!

Comment: Try to find a nonzero solution to T(x)=0=T(0).

Comment: @qbert.... i did row reduced

Comment: @Suresh_iit I saw that, and it's a fine solution. My comment is that this is about as easy as it gets.

Comment: @qbert..i still not get any examples

Comment: @Suresh_iit Oh I see now, sorry I missed that part of the question. I will offer a solution

Comment: What's wrong with simply calculating the determinant?

Comment: @OriaGruber op is asking specifically for an example of a vector not hit by the transformation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We make the following augmented system 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2&-10&-4&-2&a\\
1&-5&1&5&b\\
-1&5&3&4&c\\
-2&10&3&1&d
\end{bmatrix}
$$
inconsistent, and so find a vector not in the image. 
By row reducing (barring any mistakes) we get a row of zeros equal to the following
$$
a+6d+4b-6c
$$
as long as we insure this is nonzero, we have an inconsistent system. One may check that, for example, the vector 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix}
$$ 
is not in the range.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{pmatrix}1 & -5 & 1 & 5 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a \\ b\\c\\d\end{pmatrix} = 0$

From the third row we see $d=0$ , from the second row combined with the knowledge that $d=0$ we see that $c+2d = c+0 = 0$, so $c=0$ as well.

So overall we have now from the first row $a-5b = 0$, or $a=5b$.

So every vector you choose that looks like $\begin{pmatrix}5t \\ t \\0 \\0\end{pmatrix}$ will go to $0$, so this mapping isn't one to one.